# Looking for eco friendly biodegradable toilet cleaners for removing toilet rust, either home-made or commercial

Tags: cleaning, toilet, ecolabel

The toilet rust is a very tough stain.
I have tried:

- Vinegar alone
- Lemon juice
- Baking soda with vinegar: works a little bit

I am asking for other options that are biodegradable. Please let me know the products, and homemade recipes you have.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your answers to help me out. I tried vinegar, baking soda with vinegar, which are the so-called "popular" method by "Dr. Google" and popular magazines out there, but NONE works. I tried citric acid and it works very quickly, I don't have to leave it there for hours. However, you need to use the right toilet brush. The traditional round brush won't work, but why is it still sold everywhere?! Use the toilet brush like Joseph Joseph Flex Lite toilet brush, it reaches almost all areas.

Answer (score 3):

How are you applying the cleaning solutions? The technique is just as important as the ingredients - they need time to work, which may be difficult with a porcelain toilet bowl, as the dimensions and pool of water can interfere with the process.

You need the solution to remain on the affected area and not be diluted by the bowl of water - draining the latter as much as possible before application would be the best option.

According to [this article](https://www.hunker.com/13424047/how-to-remove-rust-from-porcelain), Vinegar and Baking Soda paste should be left on the affected area for at least an hour, followed up with a second paste of Cream of Tartar (a.k.a. Potassium bitartrate) and 3% Hydrogen Peroxide, also for an hour.

As for the eco-friendliness of these ingredients: Cream of Tartar is a byproduct of the winemaking industry and is used in cooking. Hydrogen Peroxide is considered [greener than chloride-based bleaches](https://www.greenlivingtips.com/articles/hydrogen-peroxide-tips.html), and produces water as a byproduct. Some businesses are making the switch to Hydrogen Peroxide over chloride-based bleaches, for example, [Barnhardt Cotton](https://barnhardtcotton.net/blog/the-eco-friendliness-of-hydrogen-peroxide/)

Comment: Hello Robotnik, thank you. you are right about the pool of water there. The problem is this toilet bowl cannot be drained of water, there is no shutoff valve anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to add a pumice stone to scrub the rust stains off. I use the one with a handle attached it is about $8 and will last for years. Search the Internet for “pumice stone toilet”. [image: Pumice stone]

Comment: Hello NaniBly, thank you for your answer. You are right about the tool, I tried another toilet brush Joseph Joseph Flex-Lite and it reaches almost all areas in the bowl.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Buy some all-in-one eco dishwasher tablets. Put one directly into the toilet bowl where the lime is jammed and leave it there over night (it will dissolve in the little amount of water there). In the morning just flush and the bowl should be cleaned from any lime etc. Maybe you need to do this more than one time, but it should work pretty easy and fine.

Comment: Hello Didi, I haven't tried the all-in-one eco dishwasher tablets. it is not limescale though, it is rust. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Coca cola. The acidity in Coke makes it super handy for cleaning purposes.

Comment: Coca cola can work, but it can also add stains too. I'd be careful trying to use it.